# bash script "(" unexpected only on mobile

Tags: php, bash

Recently been seeing this pop up on the apache error logs when trying to run the command bellow.

Was running fine and only seen on mobile devices.

Please help as i'm so confused as I can't find a unexpected (

Code

```
session_start();
if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile']) && !empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){
   $target_path = "upload/";
   $target = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
}
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'] , $target))
{
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = "File successfully uploaded.";
shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/upload/" . >basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.2:5000");
header("Location: stream.php");
exit;
  } 
 else {
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";

header("Location: stream.php");
exit;
    }


    ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes done so now,not all the code displayed at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A factor reset from the tablet solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code:

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/upload/" . >basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.2:5000");
```

Should be:

```
shell_exec("ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/upload/" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.2:5000");
```

Comment: Well then you have multiple errors, and the error message should have *hopefully* changed now. What is the new error from your error_log? Or what are you trying to do with ffmpeg to begin with?

Comment: The same `sh:1: syntax error: "(" unexpected` .Do you need more code ie the webpage too ?

Comment: echo out the command you are trying to execute instead of running it. copy it then go run it in bash. does it work?

Comment: Stream a uploaded file to a unicast destination. the script works when ran on a PC but not a tablet for say

Comment: A side note, the > is probably not meant to be there at all.

Comment: can you paste the exact command you ran that supposedly worked fine. > denotes that output from a command should be written to a file in linux, so i'm curious as to why it's in your command considering you follow that with a file name and options for ffmpeg. it doesn't make sense that this command would work for you..

Comment: I made an edit and am assuming maybe you just typo'd the > to begin with.

Comment: ffmpeg -re -i <filename> -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://unicast address

Comment: Okay, yeah you typo'd the > completely then. My newest edit should work fine.

Comment: Can you explain why it works fine on chrome in windows but not in chrome on the tablet as was working fine ?